# How to update project using gradle automatically when executing sonar-runner?

Tags: android, sonarqube, android-gradle-plugin, lint, sonar-runner

I am using:

- Android Studio 1.2
- SonarQube 5.1

...and I want to force the project build of Android app before passing SonarQube, maybe modifying gradle configuration file.

I have added the next lines to `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: "sonar-runner"

sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
        property "sonar.analysis.mode", "incremental"
        property 'sonar.sourceEncoding', 'UTF-8'
        property 'sonar.language', 'java'
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main"
        property 'sonar.profile', 'Android Lint'
        property 'sonar.import_unknown_files', 'true'
    }
}

subprojects {
    sonarRunner {
        sonarProperties {
            property "sonar.sources", "src/main"
        }
    }
}
```

What should I change in order to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: go to builde.gradle of module, not app

Comment: Please, can you explain a little more, @Krupal?

Comment: in gradle scripts section, you will find two build.gradle...go to first one...you are showing the second one

Comment: OK @Krupal, but... what should I add in that file? Please, can you compose an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a new line to **module** `build.gradle` file, just after **sonarRunner** task declaration:

```
sonarRunner {
    tasks.sonarRunner.dependsOn build  // <- This new line
    sonarProperties {
```